# Regular expressions and bigrams

Tags: python, regex, string

To replace punctuation with a blank space I use:

```
import re
sentence = ...
output = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', sentence)
```

I have two questions:

1. I would like to change it to allow double words separated by a hyphen: for example `"double-barreled"` should remain `"double-barreled"` and not `"double barreled"`. What's the fastest way to implement this change?
2. At a later time, I would like to replace any word that does not contain either only letters or only numbers with white space, also considering double words. For example:

   `"Tokyo2020"` > `" "`

   `"covid-19"` > `"covid-19"`

   `"cov!d-19"` > `" "`

   `"Oompa-L00mpa"` > `" "`

   Is there any clever way to implement this with regular expressions?

Comment: It's probably practical to use a collection of acceptable characters instead, such as `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-]+`

Comment: For 1: `output = re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', ' ', sentence)`

Comment: SO guidelines say to ask one question at a time. I know these might seem like related questions but in fact 2 is quite a different question from 1, because it deals with words, not characters, and I recommend you post it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that the word does not consists of only parts with digits or word chars other than digits and _ separated by a hyphen.

```
(?<!\S)(?!(?:\d+|[^\W\d_]+)(?:-(?:\d+|[^\W\d_]+))*(?!\S))\S+
```

- `(?<!\S)` Whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?:\d+|[^\W\d_]+)` Match either digits or word chars without digits and `_`
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

    - `-(?:\d+|[^\W\d_]+)` Match `-` and the same pattern as before
  - `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
  - `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3DgxUv/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZDUE7z)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"(?<!\S)(?!(?:\d+|[^\W\d_]+)(?:-(?:\d+|[^\W\d_]+))*(?!\S))\S+"
 
s = ("Tokyo2020\n"
    "Tokyo!2020\n"
    "covid-19\n"
    "cov!d-19\n"
    "Oompa-L00mpa\n"
    "double-barreled\n"
    "double barreled\n"
    "test-t9")
 
result = re.sub(pattern, "[ ]", s)
print(result)
```

Output (where `[ ]` can be a space)

```
[ ]
[ ]
covid-19
[ ]
[ ]
double-barreled
double barreled
[ ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Assuming the single words are ok (i.e. "Tokyo2020" remains "Tokyo2020" but "Tokyo!2020" becomes " ") how should I change the pattern?

Comment: @LJG Then you could add ! also as a character that could be in between using a character class.  See https://regex101.com/r/aJnUey/1

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I mean that single tokens must only consist of letters and numbers (then no symbols)

Comment: @LJG What should `Tokyo!2020` become? Right now it is being removed as it is a `word that does not contain either only letters or only numbers`

Comment: "Tokyo!2020" should be removed since it contains a symbol (!). I realized that in my texts there are single tokens containing both letters and numbers (but not symbols), which are therefore valid

Comment: Yes. My curiosity is: if I no longer wanted to delete single tokens (so no double tokens divided by an hypen) such as "Tokyo2020" how would your answer change?

Comment: @LJG If you want to match only words that consist of only digits or chars other than digits and `_` then `(?<!\S)(?:\d+|[^\W\d_]+)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/mE7JjZ/1

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:**

This regex `[^\P{P}-]+` captures all punctuations but dash and `\B-\B` captures dashes that are not surrounded by word boundaries. You can use combination of these two regex to replace the punctuations except dashbes binding two words like this.

```
[^\P{P}-]+|(\B-\B)
```

**Q2:**

This regex can capture the scenario if first word before the dash does not contain digits.

```
(^\w+)(\b-\b)(\d+|\D+)$
```